# In which episode of Doctor Who is the Tardis a Red Police Box and is there a significance for it?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification, tardis

I have seen a few pictures of a Red Police Box in the *Doctor Who* sites, but there are no particulars as to its significance. Can anyone help me out? I am trying to write a fiction based on the Red Tardis.

Comment: In the sound of drums the interior of the tardis Looks red after the Master turns it into the Paradox Engine.

Comment: Any chance that people are confusing it with BOOTH from Inspector Spacetime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may be thinking of [*The Happiness Patrol*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Happiness_Patrol) (three Seventh Doctor episodes, Season 25 Serial 2), in which the TARDIS is pink for a while. From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/25-2.htm):

> (The Doctor and Ace return to see the Tardis is now pink.)
>   ACE: Professor, look what they've done!
>   DOCTOR: Yes, it looks rather good.
>   DAISY: You look rather unhappy about something.
>   DOCTOR: On the contrary. Just admiring your handiwork. [To Ace] Huh, miserable looking thing, wasn't it?

Thanks to @Valorum who found [the full video online](https://archive.org/details/DrWho152TheHappinessPatrol1Of3/Dr+Who+-+152+-+The+Happiness+Patrol+-+1+of+3.avi) and also an image:

[image: characters standing in front of a pink TARDIS]

The significance of it in this story is that they are on a planet where sadness is illegal, and blue is associated with sadness while pink is a more jolly colour. (The episode was [intended to be a satire on Thatcherism](https://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Happiness_Patrol_(TV_story)). Some reviewers have claimed there's a gay subtext in the pink TARDIS, but this theory doesn't seem to be widely believed.)

Other than that, the TARDIS has never canonically been red, outside of jokes and spoofs:

[image: joke Red TARDIS with Russian inscription and hammer and sickle symbol]

(click for full size version). [You're not the only person to think so](https://doctorwho.livejournal.com/6431329.html) though.

Comment: i went through the internet searching for the site where i saw a Red Police Box and could not find it. maybe, as you suggest it was only a Police Box and not from the Doctor Who series, or probably a spoof. Thank you for the reply and @Valorum for the links.